# Updating via query builder in is not working

Tags: sql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I tried updating a column value using sql command, but it show general failure. Below is my code for update:

```
$name = 'ABC';
$id = 2;
$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
    ->update('companies', ['company_name' => $name], 'company_id ='.$id.'');
$result = $command->queryAll();
```

When I execute this code below message is shown to me.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error
>   The SQL being executed was: UPDATE `companies` SET `company_name`='ABC' WHERE company_id =2
>
> Error Info: Array
>   (
>       [0] => HY000
>   )

I cant find out why. Does anybody have any idea, what am I doing wrong here?

**UPD**

```
$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
    ->update('companies', ['company_name' => $name], 'company_id ='.$id.'')->execute();
```

Can not use `$command->queryAll()` with update command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of errors in your code.

First of all, why you are using `queryAll()` with `UPDATE` operation? Remove this line:

```
$result = $command->queryAll();
```

Second error - missing call of `execute()` command. Should be:

```
$command = Yii::$app->db
    ->createCommand()
    ->update('companies', ['company_name' => $name], 'company_id ='.$id.'')
    ->execute();
```

Check out documentation for [yii\db\Command](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html), especially [execute()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#execute%28%29-detail) and [queryAll()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#queryAll%28%29-detail) methods.

Comment: I actually found the mistake before your suggestion. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted so the others can know too.